# How do I find the Laplace Transform of $ \delta(t-2\pi)\cos(t) $?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

How do I find the Laplace Transform of

$$ \delta(t-2\pi)\cos(t) $$

where $\delta(t) $ is the Dirac Delta Function.

I know that it boils down to the following integral

$$ \int_{0}^\infty e^{-st}\delta(t-2\pi)\cos(t)dt $$

and I know that the answer is simply

$$ e^{-2\pi s} $$

and I know how to integrate just the Dirac Delta Function. I don't know how to integrate it as the product of another function of the same variable. It doesn't explain anywhere in the chapter in my text, either, so I'm a bit confused. I assume I'll have to integrate by parts, or something, but I'm not to sure what to do with that Delta Function in there. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Think in the sampling/shifting property of  $\delta(t)$.

Comment: $f(t)\delta (t-t')=f(t')\delta(t-t')$ and $\cos 2\pi=1$.  Does that help?

Comment: I see. This was my suspicion, but it wasn't clear to me that the delta function was "operating" upon the cosine function; I thought it was just the product of two functions of $t$.

Comment: In your integral the delta function "operates" on the product of $cos(t)$ and $e^{-st}$. It has the same effect on both functions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(t) = \delta(t-2\pi)$.

You can write $f(t)\cos(t) = \frac{1}{2}(f(t)e^{it} + f(t)e^{-it})$ by Euler's formula.

So $L\{f(t)\cos(t)\}(s) = \frac{1}{2}(F(s+i)+F(s-i)))$, (since you are doing a frequency shift by multiplying by an exponential in $t$) where $F(s) = L\{f\}(s) = e^{-2\pi s}$.

Thus, you have $L\{f(t)\cos(t)\}(s)= \frac{1}{2}[e^{-2\pi s +2\pi i} + e^{-2\pi s - 2\pi i}] = \frac{1}{2}[e^{-2\pi s}e^{2\pi i} + e^{-2\pi s}e^{-2\pi i}] =\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2 \cdot e^{-2\pi s}$, since $e^{-2\pi i} = e^{2 \pi i} = 1$.